Unable to install Ubunto 24.04 kernel 6.8.0-40 with rtbth
Instead, 6.8.0-39 was perfect. BT working.
But with 6.8.0-40, all messages as reported in many places: kernel panic signalling dkms rtbth in rtbth_core_bluez.c in line 318.

the line 318 is a problem
hdev->dev_type = HCI_PRIMARY;
HCI_PRIMARY is has been removed from linux kernel
just comment out line 318 like this and try
//hdev->dev_type = HCI_PRIMARY;
see here
